# This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a problem executing this query. Please see my code below.

```
   SELECT        (SELECT        COUNT(FilteredAppointment.activitytypecodename) AS Expr1
                      FROM            FilteredBusinessUnit INNER JOIN
                                                FilteredSystemUser ON FilteredBusinessUnit.businessunitid = FilteredSystemUser.businessunitid INNER JOIN
                                                FilteredAppointment ON FilteredSystemUser.systemuserid = FilteredAppointment.createdby
                      WHERE        (FilteredBusinessUnit.name IN (@Branch))) AS Appointment,
                         (SELECT        COUNT(FilteredLead.leadid) AS Expr1
                           FROM            FilteredBusinessUnit AS FilteredBusinessUnit_7 INNER JOIN
                                                     FilteredSystemUser AS FilteredSystemUser_7 ON FilteredBusinessUnit_7.businessunitid = FilteredSystemUser_7.businessunitid INNER JOIN
                                                     FilteredLead ON FilteredSystemUser_7.systemuserid = FilteredLead.createdby
                           WHERE        (FilteredBusinessUnit_7.name IN (@Branch)) AND (FilteredLead.new_referraltypename = 'Bank Staff')) AS Bank_Staff_Referral,
                         (SELECT        COUNT(FilteredLead_3.leadid) AS Expr1
                           FROM            FilteredBusinessUnit AS FilteredBusinessUnit_6 INNER JOIN
                                                     FilteredSystemUser AS FilteredSystemUser_6 ON FilteredBusinessUnit_6.businessunitid = FilteredSystemUser_6.businessunitid INNER JOIN
                                                     FilteredLead AS FilteredLead_3 ON FilteredSystemUser_6.systemuserid = FilteredLead_3.createdby
                           WHERE        (FilteredBusinessUnit_6.name IN (@Branch)) AND (FilteredLead_3.new_referraltypename = 'Existing Customer')) AS Customer_Referral,
                         (SELECT        COUNT(Filterednew_discoveryinterview.activityid) AS Expr1
                           FROM            FilteredBusinessUnit AS FilteredBusinessUnit_5 INNER JOIN
                                                     FilteredSystemUser AS FilteredSystemUser_5 ON FilteredBusinessUnit_5.businessunitid = FilteredSystemUser_5.businessunitid INNER JOIN
                                                     Filterednew_discoveryinterview ON FilteredSystemUser_5.systemuserid = Filterednew_discoveryinterview.createdby
                           WHERE        (FilteredBusinessUnit_5.name IN (@Branch))) AS Discovery_Interview,
                         (SELECT        COUNT(FilteredLead_2.leadid) AS Expr1
                           FROM            FilteredBusinessUnit AS FilteredBusinessUnit_4 INNER JOIN
                                                     FilteredSystemUser AS FilteredSystemUser_4 ON FilteredBusinessUnit_4.businessunitid = FilteredSystemUser_4.businessunitid INNER JOIN
                                                     FilteredLead AS FilteredLead_2 ON FilteredSystemUser_4.systemuserid = FilteredLead_2.createdby
                           WHERE        (FilteredBusinessUnit_4.name IN (@Branch))) AS Generated_Leads,
```

(SELECT  name
                               FROM FilteredBusinessUnit
                               WHERE (FilteredBusinessUnit.name IN (@Branch ))) AS BRANCH

`

The code returns results for query run against a single branch. However, an error is thrown with message" Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. "  When I select more than one branch. My guess is that the error occurs when the last block of select statement is run.

How can I write this query to display results for multiple branches

Please help me

Comment: This means that one of your sub queries are returning more than one value at a time.

Comment: Thank you Jacques Bronkhorst. I understand what this means. I need advice on how to write this query so that it returns resuls for more than one branch in the filter.

Answer (score 1):

By Selecting the @Branch Variable separately.
Here is the Updated code sample

```
 SELECT   MQ.Name AS BranchName,
      (SELECT COUNT(FilteredAppointment.activitytypecodename) AS Expr1
                  FROM  FilteredBusinessUnit 
                  INNER JOIN FilteredSystemUser ON FilteredBusinessUnit.businessunitid = FilteredSystemUser.businessunitid 
                  INNER JOINFilteredAppointment ON FilteredSystemUser.systemuserid = FilteredAppointment.createdby
                  WHERE (FilteredBusinessUnit.name = MQ.Name)) AS Appointment,
                  (SELECT COUNT(FilteredLead.leadid) AS Expr1
                       FROM  FilteredBusinessUnit AS FilteredBusinessUnit_7 
                       INNER JOIN FilteredSystemUser AS FilteredSystemUser_7 ON FilteredBusinessUnit_7.businessunitid = FilteredSystemUser_7.businessunitid 
                       INNER JOIN FilteredLead ON FilteredSystemUser_7.systemuserid = FilteredLead.createdby
                       WHERE  (FilteredBusinessUnit_7.name = MQ.Name) AND (FilteredLead.new_referraltypename = 'Bank Staff')) AS Bank_Staff_Referral,
                     (SELECT COUNT(FilteredLead_3.leadid) AS Expr1
                       FROM            FilteredBusinessUnit AS FilteredBusinessUnit_6 INNER JOIN
                                                 FilteredSystemUser AS FilteredSystemUser_6 ON FilteredBusinessUnit_6.businessunitid = FilteredSystemUser_6.businessunitid INNER JOIN
                                                 FilteredLead AS FilteredLead_3 ON FilteredSystemUser_6.systemuserid = FilteredLead_3.createdby
                       WHERE        (FilteredBusinessUnit_6.name = MQ.Name) AND (FilteredLead_3.new_referraltypename = 'Existing Customer')) AS Customer_Referral,
                     (SELECT        COUNT(Filterednew_discoveryinterview.activityid) AS Expr1
                       FROM            FilteredBusinessUnit AS FilteredBusinessUnit_5 INNER JOIN
                                                 FilteredSystemUser AS FilteredSystemUser_5 ON FilteredBusinessUnit_5.businessunitid = FilteredSystemUser_5.businessunitid INNER JOIN
                                                 Filterednew_discoveryinterview ON FilteredSystemUser_5.systemuserid = Filterednew_discoveryinterview.createdby
                       WHERE        (FilteredBusinessUnit_5.name = MQ.Name)) AS Discovery_Interview,
                     (SELECT        COUNT(FilteredLead_2.leadid) AS Expr1
                       FROM            FilteredBusinessUnit AS FilteredBusinessUnit_4 INNER JOIN
                                                 FilteredSystemUser AS FilteredSystemUser_4 ON FilteredBusinessUnit_4.businessunitid = FilteredSystemUser_4.businessunitid INNER JOIN
                                                 FilteredLead AS FilteredLead_2 ON FilteredSystemUser_4.systemuserid = FilteredLead_2.createdby
                       WHERE        (FilteredBusinessUnit_4.name = MQ.Name)) AS Generated_Leads
FROM FilteredBusinessUnit MQ--I Assume this is where the Branch Name  Is kept
WHERE MQ.Name In (@Branch)
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but when i select more than one branch in the filter it merges the query result for all selected branches as one and displays all results under the first branch selected. Example when i select only lagos branch
Branch Name| Appointment |Leads |Phone Call
Lagos    |          50 |100 |189
but if i select Lagos and Abuja
Branch Name| Appointment| Leads| Phone Call
Lagos    |     250    |    210  | 589

Comment: @DavidEdokpayi Try selecting the Branch Name and not the Variable '@Branch' you will Have to rework your query a bit to achieve this. I will update the Code to reflect what I am trying to say

Comment: @DavidEdokpayi It has been updated, please have a look at the revised Code

Comment: I tried the update you sent, but when i select more than one filter it throws this error 'execution failed for dataset "dataset1". Incorrect Syntax error near "," Incorrect Syntax error near ","....'. When i researched on the error it indicates that the result string is merged and i need a function to split the result string

Comment: @DavidEdokpayi It is difficult to compile this query if I do not have an idea of your data structure. Copy the Query in Sql Management Studio and execute it. This would give you a more detailed description of the error.